# Adding seconds using DATEADD is returning a value rounded to minutes - why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I need to add LAST_DT (provided as a smalldatetime but without hhmmss) and LAST_TM (provided as nvarchar) to calculate a true DateTime value.
I'm trying to use [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) to increment the date provided with the hhmmss from LAST_TM.
Hours and Minutes are adding successfully, but Seconds are being rounded up or down to Minutes.
Here's my code

```
DECLARE @LAST_DT smalldatetime = '2017-10-18'
DECLARE @LAST_TM nvarchar(6) = '153954'

SELECT
 @LAST_DT
 ,@LAST_TM
 ,DATEADD(minute, CAST(substring(@LAST_TM,3,2) AS INT),
   DATEADD(hour, CAST(left(@LAST_TM,2) AS INT),@LAST_DT)) AS Dt_HhMm
 ,Right(@LAST_TM,2) As Secs
 ,DATEADD(second, CAST(Right(@LAST_TM,2) AS INT),
   DATEADD(minute, CAST(substring(@LAST_TM,3,2) AS INT),
    DATEADD(hour, CAST(left(@LAST_TM,2) AS INT),@LAST_DT))) AS Dt_HhMmSs
```

and corresponding results

```
LAST_DT      LAST_TM  Dt_HhMm               Secs   Dt_HhMmSs
2017-10-18   153954   2017-10-18 15:39:00   54     2017-10-18 15:40:00
```

Why are the seconds being rounded to nearest minutes?

(I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a minimal and reproducible example.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  I think I have fixed that so you can reproduce it...

Answer (score 2):

I guess I practically answered my own question. LAST_DT is smalldatetime, which by definition doesn't include seconds.
Casting LAST_DT as  datetime:

```
SELECT
 CC.LAST_DT
 ,CC.LAST_TM
 ,DATEADD(second, CAST(Right(CC.LAST_TM,2) AS INT),
   DATEADD(minute, CAST(substring(CC.LAST_TM,3,2) AS INT),
    DATEADD(hour, CAST(left(CC.LAST_TM,2) AS INT),CAST(CC.LAST_DT As datetime)))) 
    AS Dt+HhMmSs
```

fixes the problem.

I am curious why smalldatetime would display with seconds when that is explicitly not part of the data type? That's very confusing/misleading.

Comment: I'd also be interested to see if anyone has a better/faster/more concise way of performing this addition to return the datetime value!

Comment: `why smalldatetime would display with seconds` that is just how SSMS present the data

Comment: Smalldatetime displays seconds because that's just the default display for datetime. As for "simplifying" it, I suppose you could use a combination of integer division and modulo? e.g. `DATEADD(SECOND, LAST_TM / 10000 * 3600 + (LAST_TM % 10000) / 100 * 60 + LAST_TM % 100, LAST_DT)`. At least that avoids the substring/cast functions.

Comment: That's much nicer thanks @ZLK (I hadn't realised you could use arithmetic operations on nvarchar without casting/converting it first).

Comment: Isn't the default display for (the time portion of) datetime hh:mm:ss.000 ?

Answer (score 1):

you can just convert LAST_DT to datetime and then ADD the LAST_TM in HH:MM:SS format

```
CONVERT(datetime, CC.LAST_DT) +  STUFF(STUFF(CC.LAST_TM, 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':')
```